# Monitor all outgoing HTTPS or SSL request

Tags: linux, ssl, networking, https

I would like to monitor all ssl request from my machine; specifically youtube requests.

**Constraints**

- No proxy should be set in my browser.
- It should work as a logger that work in background

**Data Available**

Following information about my environment

- **OS** Linux
- **Tools** SSLStrip, SSLDump
- **KEY** Obviously as it's monitoring my traffic so I have public and private keys too, if needed.

I am not sure these tools are enough in order track all the traffic of https going through my local machine or not. But, I want some tools to track all outgoing https request from my machine.

Comment: From your machine or your browser? Because of it's the browser, an extension can be helpful

Comment: No I am using linux so I want to log all the HTTPS request using my kernel

Answer (score -1):

To decrypt https on your machine you have two way :

- Do a MITM with a certificate you own
- For each software you want to monitor, do something custom (use a plugin or get the temporary key they use)

For example, you could use mitmproxy. Detailed explanations ca be found there: https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/

Comment: how to own a certificate can you explain it furhter?

Comment: Simple : generate a private key, them a certificate. You own it. Tell your client to trust it, them you can MITM

Comment: @Tom, Please give more detailed answer or provide useful links.